# Singularity Classification

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

Suppose that I have the following function:

$$f(z)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{1}{z})}\right)$$

If I'm trying to characterize singularities, I know that singularities will be found whenever $z=\frac{1}{n\pi}$.  Further, we can deduce that $z=0$ will be a non-isolated singularity, as the singularities begin to cluster around eachother as z goes to 0.  How do we characterize the other singularities though?  Are they essential or poles?  I'm not really sure how to make this distinction, as I can't evaluate the limits (the function goes crazy at each singularity).

Answer (score 1):

All the isolated singularities will be essential.

By restricting to real $z$ you can see that your function does not have a limit as $z$ tends to each singularity. (Note that $|f| \to \infty$ when we approach a pole and that $f$ has a proper limit when we approach a removable singularity).

Comment: I thought that essential singularities arise when the right and left limits are not equal?...

Comment: @user108149 "right" and "left" limits doesn't make much sense when the variable is complex. But with some generous interpretation, that's *one* of many ways the limit as you approach the singualarity may fail to exist. Note however that $\exp(-1/z^2)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ even though the "left" and "right" limits are both equal to $0$.